# How to write Java RESTful Based Axis2 Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, apache-axis

I was reading a lot of information on the Internet, I promise, but I didn't find any post or tutorial in which appears **How to write Java RESTful Based Axis2 Web Service**

I don't know if this task has sense, because I have only read about RESTful Web Services or Web Services based on Axis2. It could be I have mixing differents ideas about how to develop Web Services and so, I need help. What can I do?
**Where can I learn how to develop a RESTful Web Service based on Axis2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write a RESTful Web Service using Axis2. Axis2 is suited for SOAP web services.

For RESTful Web Services you have to use some other framework like [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)

Edit: it seems you can indeed write a REST WS using Axis2 (yet Axis2 is mostly used for SOAP services).

Comment: But I read that the advantages of using Axis2 are that support both technologies, SOAP and REST. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Axis2

Comment: @JoséMaríaValbae My recommendation is that if you're new to web services in Restfull get you started using Jersey. As much as I can say that internet is not very common because they are two different technologies SOAP and Restfull

Comment: I have been using Axis2 for years and I have always seen it being used for SOAP services. I am reading right now it supports a REST interface, but it requires a WSDL, so you are going to have both a SOAP and a REST interface. That's pretty confusing, I would avoid it. Anyway here is a tutorial: http://wso2.com/library/3726/#RESTfull%20Services%20in%20Axis2

Comment: Thanks to both, I would try to develop my project under these recommendations.